# ffmpeg fmp4 segment encryption

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, drm

I'm searching for a solution to protect HLS streams using DRM/AES encryption.

Currently, it seems that this is only working with .ts segments not with .m4s segments and .ts files again don't work with HEVC / 4k HDR content, so it seems I'm 100% stuck at this point.

There is also a report from another user (4 years ago) with exactly the same issue: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7138
Is there any kind of workaround? Maybe outside of ffmpeg?

Comment: Have you looked into [Bento4](https://www.bento4.com/)? It supports HLS with fMP4 segments... in particular, you're probably looking for [mp4encrypt](https://www.bento4.com/documentation/mp4encrypt/).

Comment: I also was in touch what that, but in most cases I fail due to SAMPLE-AES support for most players ...